# Apache2 uninstall issues

Tags: apache

I had to recently uninstall Apache2 due to some broken package issues.

However, when I check with

```
`$ whereis apache2` Iget response `apache2:`
```

I have used `$ sudo -rf /etc/apache2`,`$ sudo apt-get remove apache2-common`
 `$ sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2` `$ sudo apt autoremove` but I have still not managed to completely remove all traces of the Apache2 from my Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

I shall highly appreciate if someone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the commands above you completely removed Apache2.

- `apt remove` removes the binaries of a package
- `apt purge` removes everything related to the apache2 package including the configuration files.

In your case `whereis` is showing that there are no binaries, sources or manual pages of the `apache2` package.